# Project not compiling using Kotlin in Project

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrolambda

I have a problem Compiling my program when I add some class in Kotlin in it. When I do a clean of the project, and Start running it, the next error is prompt:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileRetrolambdaMyProject'.
```

> Process 'command '/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

The thing is that if I execute again the project it works perfectly. So basically I have to build the project twice in order to execute the project.

I need this to be fixed because I build the final version in Jenkins and this is giving me problems.

Any clues on how to fix it?

**Edit:**

This are the unique warnings that it gives me, but as I said, they are warnings, not errors, and if I Run again the project it works perfectly :

```
Warning:(31, 57) Parameter 'buttonView' is never used, could be renamed to _
Warning:(40, 46) Parameter 'v' is never used, could be renamed to _
Warning:(56, 48) Parameter 'v' is never used, could be renamed to _
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileRetrolambdaMyProject'.
> Process 'command '/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Comment: Please share the full ouput of a gradle clean build on the command line

Comment: These warnings will not stop you from building. Open terminal and run `gradlew build` and post the  result here.

Comment: Its fixed, I uploaded the version of retrolambda and its working now

Comment: Please either delete your question then or answer and accept it - so it is closed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with RetroLambda Library, following this issue on Github:
https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda/issues/105

The solution is to add :

```
retrolambda {
    jvmArgs '-noverify'
}
```

to my gradle, and upgrading the Retrolambda library to `version 3.7.0`.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and tried the following things:

via Android Studio:

- Build > Clean Project
- File > Invalidate Caches / Restart

via command line:

- ./gradlew build --refresh-dependencies

These three approaches solved most of the problems like this I had before, but in this case the only thing that helped was to **delete all build folders in my project manually** (build folder in project root and in all modules like *app* and others if you have more).